# Autodesk Eagle board testing spots

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

Is there any way to make a "bald" spot along a route (basically a via without the hole) so that I can test the connection for troubleshooting?

Comment: Yes, most people make a component called a TP with a footprint that is a single pad, another advantage is that it is very good when the TP is also indicated in the schematic. Adhoc solution - you can expose any trace by putting geometry on the negative mask layer by editing the property of the trace or a manually drawn feature on soldermask layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are elements called "test points" (TP), which are simply an exposed pad of any form you like (there are many cicular and rectangular shapes available).

Press "place component", find a library "testpad" (or download it if not present; should be there actually)

[image: screenshot]

Just attach it on your line like any other component and you're done, it will show up as a pad that you can move around on PCB.